# How to create a file in Linux assembly

Tags: linux, file, assembly, nasm

I have the following code:

```
section .text
    global _start       ;must be declared for using gcc
_start:                     ;tell linker entry point
    mov ecx, 2      ;read-write perms
    mov ebx, name       ;name of file
    mov eax, 8      ;system call number (sys_creat)
    int 0x80        ;call kernel
    mov eax, 1      ;system call number (sys_exit)
    int 0x80        ;call kernel

section .data
name    db  'C:\\test.txt',0xa
```

It is meant to create a file (test.txt) in the C drive however doesn't work, what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: `int 0x80` is how you perform a system call on 32-bit Linuxes. Are you running this on a Linux machine? If so, I doubt `c:\test.txt` is a valid path. If you're targetting Windows you'd have to use a different set of APIs, and for DOS it'd be yet another API.

Comment: What is `C drive` for linux?

Comment: While there is no C drive, the backslash isn't a directory separator so that's not an issue per se. More problematic is that file name should be 0 terminated not line feed. Indeed the above code does work if that's fixed.

Comment: Ah okay thank you, I am running the script on an online linux tester since I haven't yet worked out how to run assembler scripts on windows, I will look up how to do that. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, syscall=8 is sys_creat, not write.

But the easiest way to find out what is happening is looking at the strace output of the program. There you can see if the syscall succeeded, and if not, what is the error value. (errno)

Afaik creat(2) is not used anymore, and Open(2) with O_CREAT in the second argument is used nowadays.